# Do you know of any functions which resemble this function?

Tags: functions

I am looking for a function which is non $0$ between two $x$ coordinates and $0$ for all other coordinates. I have found one function like this, which is $\frac{1}{x^{\infty}+1}$: see image. However, it is not ideal, as $1^{\infty}$ is indeterminate. Do you know of any other such functions? I have also played around with equations involving square roots, however this doesn't seem to work as then the function is undefined for all values not between the x coordinates, which is something that I don't want.

[image: Image of function]

Comment: What kind of functions are you looking for? It's very trivial if you allow for piecewise functions. (Though $x^\infty$ is hardly a well-defined, good notation.)

Comment: Yes, @Mather: What is your definition of function? The answer Mike Pierce gave is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}1 \text{ if } |x|<1\\0 \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Dunno why this is downvoted....

Answer (score 1):

What about smooth bump functions?